# Join two tables by comparing equal value on two columns

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, nhibernate-criteria

For simplicity and clarity, assume I have these three tables.

**Employee**
[
id
]

**EmployeeName**
[
employeeId,
name
]

**EmployeeAddress**
[
employeeId,
address
]

The only properties/relationships defined are in the 'sub-tables' EmployeeName & EmployeeAddress

- EmployeeName BelongsTo Employee
- EmployeeAddress BelongsTo Employee

There **are no properties/relationships** (collections) in the main Employee table such as

- Employee HasMany EmployeeName
- Employee HasMany EmployeeAdress.

I want to **perform a join using DetachedCriteria between EmployeeName and EmployeeAddress** *only* **(not involving Employee)**, as such

> select EmployeeName.name, EmployeeAddress.address 
>   from EmployeeName inner join EmployeeAddress 
>  
>   where EmployeeName.employeeId = EmployeeAddress.employeeId and
>         EmployeeAddress.address like '%somelocation%' order by EmployeeAddress.address

Comment: So your mappings don't have any relationships between Employee and EmployeeName/EmployeeAddress tables?

Comment: Yads, yes there are no mappings from Employee to EmployeeName/EmployeeAddress (no HasMany relationships in Employee class). The inverse however is true (BelongsTo relationships in EmployeeName and EmployeeAddress classes). Basically I'm trying to avoid collections due to some business logic.

Comment: Mauricio, I can try HQL, but does this mean I have stumbled upon something that DetachedCriteria is unable to do vs HQL? It would be nice though if I can still use DetachedCriteria to have some standard way of doing things. So far all my queries have been in DetachedCriteria form.

Comment: HQL is easier for some things, and I think it would be useful here. Bottom line: use the right tool for the job. Don't try to shoehorn everything into Criteria (or NHibernate for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the query you're looking for and haven't tested if it actually works.. but it may help you:

```
var addressCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<EmployeeAddress>("ea")
                                      .Add(Restrictions.Like("ea.Address", "somelocation", MatchMode.Anywhere));
var nameCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<EmployeeName>("en")
                                   .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("en.Employee", addressCriteria))
                                   .SetProjection(Projections.Property("en.Name"));
```

Comment: This works. I've tried this in fact. But I realized I cannot sort the final outer results based on property of the subquery e.g sort by Address.